# Detect that Google Map is in full screen mode

Tags: google-maps

My map shows the deault full screen control.  Is there a way that I can detect that the map is in full screen mode or is there an event that is fired when the user click this button?

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 - how to detect when map changes to full screen mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620850/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-detect-when-map-changes-to-full-screen-mode)

Comment: I posted an answer to this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620850/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-detect-when-map-changes-to-full-screen-mode/

Answer (score -1):

I have met the same problem that needs to show some data over the full screen map.(do not need to when when the map is not in full screen mode.)

Comment: Use comments if you are not really answering the Question