# Google Maps API v3 - how to detect when map changes to full screen mode?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to detect when the user clicks the default fullscreen mode button?

These are the map options I'm using:

```
var mapOptions = {
            center: {
                lat: 40.907192,
                lng: 20.036871
            },
            zoom: 2,
            fullscreenControl: true
        };
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Check out my solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699755/toogle-fullscreen-view-event-for-google-maps/47700054#47700054

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if you want to detect the actual click event or just the state change between full screen and not. I needed to do the latter. The two things you need to know are that a) when the map size changes, the map will fire the `bounds_changed` event and b) within your event handler for that, you need to compare the map div's size with the size of the entire screen. Do this like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'bounds_changed', onBoundsChanged );

function onBoundsChanged() {
    if ( $(map.getDiv()).children().eq(0).height() == window.innerHeight &&
         $(map.getDiv()).children().eq(0).width()  == window.innerWidth ) {
        console.log( 'FULL SCREEN' );
    }
    else {
        console.log ('NOT FULL SCREEN');
    }
}
```

Note that getDiv() returns your own div that you passed to the Map() constructor. That div doesn't get resized for full screen - its child does. So that part where I'm getting the child of the map's div is correct but a little unwieldy. You could also rewrite that more briefly like this and it will work but this could break in the future if Google changes the map div's class name:

```
if ( $( '.gm-style' ).height() == window.innerHeight &&
     $( '.gm-style' ).width()  == window.innerWidth ) {
```

Comment: The 'bounds_changed' event is also triggered when the map is panned/zoomed without changing to fullscreen

Comment: `bounds_changed` event also triggers if you use `fitBounds()` method of google maps somewhere in your code. For that, I had to put a flag and check if the event was triggered because of `fitBounds()` method.

Answer (score 6):

DaveBurns answer worked with some modifications because I don't use jQuery. Also I needed to use clientHeight and clientWidth

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(
  map,
  'bounds_changed',
  onBoundsChanged,
);

function onBoundsChanged() {
  if (
    map.getDiv().firstChild.clientHeight === window.innerHeight &&
    map.getDiv().firstChild.clientWidth === window.innerWidth
  ) {
    console.log('FULL SCREEN');
  } else {
    console.log('NOT FULL SCREEN');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution it is working for me:

```
/** Full Screen event */

$(document).bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function() {
    var isFullScreen = document.fullScreen ||
        document.mozFullScreen ||
        document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    if (isFullScreen) {
        console.log('fullScreen!');
    } else {
        console.log('NO fullScreen!');
    }
});
```

Comment: for ie11, also add "MSFullscreenChange"

Comment: I think, this will be triggered when the browser is full-screened. Which is what I don't want. I want an event that only gets triggered when maps is full-screened. And that event is `bounds_changed`. See @DaveBurns answer for reference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [HTML5 Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) which has the [fullscreenchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Notification) event:

> "When fullscreen mode is successfully engaged, the document which
>   contains the element receives a fullscreenchange event. When
>   fullscreen mode is exited, the document again receives a 
>   fullscreenchange event".

Please note that

> "For the moment not all browsers are using the unprefixed version of the API".

So, for instance, in Mozilla Firefox the event handler would look like this

```
document.onmozfullscreenchange = function(event) { 
    console.log("Full screen change")
}
```