# "Toggle fullscreen view" event for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there a way to capture event where a user clicks toggle fullscreen view button on the map?
[image: toggle full screen view]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HTML5 Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) which has the [fullscreenchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Notification) event:

> "When fullscreen mode is successfully engaged, the document which
>   contains the element receives a fullscreenchange event. When
>   fullscreen mode is exited, the document again receives a 
>   fullscreenchange event".

Please note All browsers implement this APIs. Nevertheless some implement it with prefixed names with slightly different spelling; e.g., instead of `requestFullscreen()`, there is `MozRequestFullScreen()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me to come up with the solution (posted below)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which worked for me:

```js
const onFullScreen = (cb) => {
    const eventNames = [
        'fullscreenchange',
        'webkitfullscreenchange',
        'mozfullscreenchange'
    ];

    eventNames.map(e => document.addEventListener(e, (event) => {
         const isFullScreen = document['fullScreen'] ||
               document['mozFullScreen'] || document['webkitIsFullScreen'];

         return cb({ isFullScreen, event });
    }));
};
```

Comment: @AswathyBalan Checking the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Prefixing), there is no IE equivalent value for fullscreen. I instead had to rely on `msFullscreenElement` existence. So my `isFullScreen` calculation included an existence check for `document.msFullscreenElement`. I also had to add `MSFullscreenChange` to the events getting listened to.